# need to convert char* array to string array

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I'm building a commandline in C++ and for some reason, comparisons between strings aren't working.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    bool sufficient_args = argc > 1;

    if (sufficient_args)
    {

        if (argv[1] == "--version" || argv[1] == "--v")
        {
        
            xsh::console_write("version", xsh::versionID);
        
        } else if (argv[1] == "--repo" || argv[1] == "--r")
        {

            xsh::console_write("repository", xsh::repo_url);
            
        } else if (argv[1] == "--docs" || argv[1] == "--d" || argv[1] == "--help" || argv[1] == "--h")
        {

            xsh::console_write("documentation", xsh::docs_url);
        
        } else if (argv[1] == "--credit" || argv[1] == "--c")
        {

            xsh::console_write("credit", xsh::credit);

        } else
        {

            xsh::throw_error(412, "invalid argument(s) found");

        }




    } else
    {

        xsh::throw_error(212, "insufficient arguments");

    }

    std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Im not getting any syntax errors, but when I run the .exe file with an argument such as --help or --credit, it runs the following code;

```cpp
xsh::throw_error(412, "invalid argument(s) found");
```

which means that argv[1] was not interpreted as the same data type as "--help".

what do I do?

Comment: `char*` is not a string. It is a pointer to `char`. You can use c-style function for string comparisons, or you can wrap it with `std::string_view` or copy it into a `std::string`

Comment: yeah i realized my mistake and edited my question. how do i convert a char* array to a string array?

Comment: Don't bother with converting `argv` into an array of `string`s. You won't see much of an advantage over converting them one at a time as you need them and if you convert and don't use, that's time wasted.

Comment: so can I just swap char* argv[] with std::string argv[]?

Comment: @user18507743 No, because `main()` doesn't accept `std::string[]` for its `argv` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Thats not how you compare `char *` 'strings' in c++

either use `strcmp`

```
if(strcmp (argv[1] ,"--version") == 0)
```

or convert to c++ `std::string`

```
  std::string arg1(argv[1]);
  if (argv1 == "--version")
```

Comment: You can also wrap them via `std::string_view`.

Comment: @ALX23z TIL about string_view - ty

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly normal. You're comparing `char*`, meaning that you're comparing **POINTERS** to `char` arrays... And these are **NOT** strings!

Also, using `char*` in C++ is, globally, a very bad idea. You must use real strings, like `std::string` which is part of C++ standard.

EDIT (see comments): Conversion of C array to C++ structure:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

....


std::vector<std::string> args ;
for (int i=0;i<argc;i++)
  args.push_back(std::string(argv[i]) ;
```

Usage: use `args[X]` instead of `argv[X]`, and operator "==" will work normally. Not tested against constant literal strings, if it doesn't work, try something like `if (args[1].compare("--version")==0)` if the compiler whines about not finding a suitable function.

Comment: so can I use string argv[] instead of char* argv[]?

Comment: @user18507743 You'll use `std::string(argv[x])` to be more precise - call to a constructor. But it would be better to fully convert your `argv` C vector into a `std::vector<std::string>` as a first operation, to avoid constructing objects constantly for nothing, and use directly the C++ structure instead of `argv`.

Comment: how do i convert argv to std::vector<std::string>

Comment: @user18507743 I've edited my answer, please check it (at end).

Comment: i did that and it had no errors but now when i run a command it doesn't print anything, even if the command is invalid

Comment: @user18507743 Then you need to update your question with more detail about that.

Comment: @user18507743 Yep, your initial question is still with non-working code, so... Will be difficult to help you more. Your initial question is, AFAIC, answered, and you should ask another question with a C++-compliant code (and maybe avoid your `xsh::` commands for test's sake and use normal `stdout` output and standard C++ `throw`, too.

Answer (score 0):

The `argv[]` is an array of `char*` and the string literals you compare them against are `const char *`. What you are comparing are pointers and the argv[] will never contain pointers to the string constants in your code and all compares will be false. What you want to compare is what the pointers point at and you can do that using `strcmp()` in the good old C style.

Converting `argv[]` into a `std::vector<std::string>` is a possibility to pull this into C++ land and you can do that by emplacing `argv[i]` into a vector in a loop.

But since you probably never use the strings again after parsing the command line it would be easier to implicitly convert the command line arguments to std::string (or string_view) by comparing them with `std::string` (string_view) literals:

```
using namespace std::literals;
...
if (argv[1] == "--version"s || argv[1] == "--v"s)
```

or

```
using namespace std::literals;
...
if (argv[1] == "--version"sv || argv[1] == "--v"sv)
```

The `s` and `sv` after the "" makes them `std::string` and `std::string_view` literals respectively. And then the overloaded `operator==()` is used and implicitly converts the first argument to the same type.